# Pytorch: Why does altering the scale of the loss functions improve the convergence in some models?

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have a question surrounding a pretty complex loss function I have.
This is a variational autoencoder loss function and it is fairly complex. 
 It is made of two reconstruction losses, KL divergence and a discriminator as a regularizer. All of those losses are on the same scale, but I have found out that increasing one of the reconstruction losses by a factor of 20 (while leaving the rest on the previous scale) heavily increases the performance of my model. 
Since I am still fairly novice on DL, I dont completely understand why this happens, or how I could identify this sort of thing on successive models. 
Any advice/explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize your setting first:

```
loss = alpha1 * loss1 + alpha2 * loss2
```

When computing the gradients for backpropagation, we compute back through this formular. By backpropagating through our error function we get the gradient:

```
dError/dLoss
```

To continue our propagation downwards, we now want to compute `dError/dLoss1` and `dError/dLoss2`.

`dError/dLoss1` can be expanded to `dError/dLoss * dLoss/dLoss1` via the cain rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).
We already computed `dError/dLoss` so we only need to compute `dLoss` derived with respect to `dLoss1`, which is

`dLoss/dLoss1 = alpha1`

The backpropagation now continues until we reach our weights (`dLoss1/dWeight`). The gradient our weight receives is:

```
dError/dWeight = dError/dLoss * dLoss/dLoss1 * dLoss1/dWeight = dError/dLoss * alpha1 * dLoss1/dWeight
```

As you can see, the gradient used to update our weight does now depend on `alpha1`, the factor we use to scale `Loss1`.
If we increase `alpha1` while not changing `alpha2` the gradients depending on `Loss1` will have higher different impact than the gradients of `Loss2` and therefor changing the optimization of our model.

Comment: So because I am changing the gradients this way, I am probably avoiding some local minima that might cause my NN to get stuck right? But what I don't quite understand is that, if I remove alpha 1, loss 1 converges anyway (albeit slower), while loss 2 stays in a local minima. Also, is there anyway to be able to detect this kind of behavior in loss functions?

Comment: With "remove alpha1" do you mean chaning the formula to `loss = loss1 + alpha2 * loss2`? This would be equivalent to setting `alpha1` to 1. In that case you would still optimize towards loss1. If removing alpha1 means you change the formula to `loss = alpha2 * loss2` you should not optimize loss1. Thus optimizing loss2 may shape the network to give lesser loss1 a decrease of loss1 could of course happen by chance.

Comment: In the end the gradient of a weight is `dError/dWeight = dError/dLoss * (alpha1 * dLoss1/dWeight + alpha2 * dLoss2/dWeight)`. By changing alpha1 and alpha2 you can control which loss function "has a higher share" on the gradient. Choosing optimal alpha1 and alpha2s is called hyperparameter tuning. This may be worth a read ;) https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-hyperparameters-and-how-to-tune-the-hyperparameters-in-a-deep-neural-network-d0604917584a

Comment: Those are fair comments, it is just that, in my specific case, when you set the alpha1 to 1, the model gets stuck for one of the tasks (which is one of the reconstructions) while the other reconstruction improves. In a way, loss 1 gets stuck in a local minima while loss two doesnt. Thanks for the link, I will read it in depth :)